# Odd padding under my buttons (only in Chrome) / CSS

Tags: html, css

My problem is simple, in Chrome why do I to have a few pixels of padding under my buttons:

```
<div id="menubar">
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="button">
            <Button>Button 1</Button>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <Button>Button 2</Button>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <Button>Button 3</Button>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <Button>Button 4</Button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="menubar">
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="button">
            <Button>Button 1</Button>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <Button>Button 2</Button>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <Button>Button 3</Button>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <Button>Button 4</Button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="menubar">
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="button">
            <Button>Button 1</Button>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <Button>Button 2</Button>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <Button>Button 3</Button>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <Button>Button 4</Button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#menubar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    display: table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    border:1px #ff0000 solid;
}
#menu {
    display: table-row;
}
#menu .button {
    display: table-cell;
    height:100%;
}
#menu .button Button {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vPkNd/8/

The buttons should occupy the entire height of the container. This works perfectly fine in Mozilla but there is this odd padding in Chrome. I've tried removing padding and margins everywhere.

Anyone?

Answer (score 3):

change this style:

```
#menu .button Button {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
}
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that. Thanks @Keith, that solved it!

Comment: Does this affect anything in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue similar to this where I needed to add some Chrome specific CSS to fix the issue. Adding this CSS should fix Chrome and leave IE and FF alone.

```
/* This CSS code is only used by chrome */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    #menu .button button {
        display:table-cell;
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
        border:0px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set margin padding and boder to 0 to your button, like.

```
#menu .button button {
display:table-cell;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
border:0px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vPkNd/13/